# Prevent App Install On Andriod By Removing Package Installer

Tags: applications, 2.3-gingerbread, installation, uninstallation

I know there are lot's of questions about this, but I haven't seen any that specifically match my question. I am trying to lock down 
a galaxy player 5.0 for a friend, so that it is virtually impossible to install other apps-unless you know what you are doing. I rooted it, downloaded Mobogenie onto my 
computer to back up the apps in case I want them back again, and started uninstalling apps with a 3rd party app, DuBoost or something like that. Now I am wondering,  if  I uninstall 
the package installer(having backed it up first) will it be possible to reinstall it with Mobogenie if I later want to install
some more apps? I don't really want to render it useless permanately, so I didn't know if anyone else tried the same thing?

Comment: So you want to rob the device even of the possibility for app (security) updates? Really? In that case be prepared you might need to flash the ROM again. I'm not 100% sure, but I'd say even `adb install` would need the package installer to perform its job.

Comment: That is true, i hadn't thought of the updating part, although the device will will not access internet in this situation. (other than, of course, if i decide later to do add apps or something, with the package installer back on the device). So the device really doesn't need updates to function

Comment: Keep security in mind, updates might be needed. Though looking at the tags used: a mistake, or did you really mean Android 2.3 here? If you really mean it, of course there are not that many security updates to be expected anymore ;)

Comment: :) yes, very old build i know. The tag is correct. Thanks for the security reminder tho.